# money market funds lock-up shares

Tags: united-states, money-market

Do money market funds in the U.S. offer locking up shares for short-term (less than three months)? The analogy I'm thinking of is checking v/s savings accounts offered by commercial banks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more as to what you mean by the analogy of checking v/s savings.

Comment: In the UK, at least, there are savings accounts where you can get better interest rates if you "_lock up_" your savings for fixed terms (typically 1 to 5 years). There are also "_notice accounts_" with a better rate of interest where you have to give (typically) 30-120 days notice before withdrawal. [**cont**]

Comment: [**cont**] Are either of these the sense of "_locking up_" you are talking about when you ask about "_locking up shares for short-term (less than three months)_"? Because, as far as I know, there is no equivalent to "_locking up_" with shares: you are free to sell them whenever you want (providing there's a buyer) and you don't get any "bonus" by promising not to sell. Please [edit] your question to clarify...